# How to get list of to-be-upgraded packages using apt-get?

Tags: apt, software-updates

I am curious if there is a script friendly way to compute the equivalent of `apt list --upgradeable`. That produces a nice output with exactly one upgrade candidate per line, very parseable. BUT, `apt` also warns:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

So I feel I should use venerable `apt-get` instead. Unfortunately, the output for that looks something like:

```
apt-get -s --no-download dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbus libdbus-1-3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bash gcc-8-base gpgv libedit2 libgcc1 libprocps7 libpsl5 libselinux1 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libsepol1 libsqlite3-0 libstdc++6 perl-base
  procps publicsuffix rsyslog twigpilot-core
18 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
...
```

Which is much less parseable. So I was hoping for some way to get `apt-get` update to print a more succinct list like `apt` would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use Ubuntu regularly but how about this:

```
$ apt-get -s --no-download dist-upgrade -V | grep '=>' | awk '{print$1}'
```

It prints one package per line.  As described in `man apt-get`:

```
   -V, --verbose-versions
       Show full versions for upgraded and installed packages. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Show-Versions.
```

Comment: Yes, this helps. If I wanted to do it entirely from command line, I think I could use `apt-get -V --no-download -s dist-upgrade | grep "^  .*" | cut -d"(" -f1`

Comment: But I'll have python so just getting the -V, and noting that all new/updated packages are preceded by unique whitespace, is enough to make them easily parseable.

Answer (score 2):

Is `apt-show-versions -u` what you are looking for? From its [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt-show-versions):

> **`-u`**, **`--upgradeable`**
>
>   Print only upgradeable packages

List all packages available for upgrade in a text file and display them in column format:

```
apt-show-versions -u | column -t > debupdlist-$(date '+%Y%m%d').txt
```

List the names of upgradeable packages:

```
apt-show-versions -u | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Does this always produce the same list of package that would actually get upgraded? What if there's a newer version of a package but it can't be installed due to missing dependencies or conflicts? What about pins? What about held packages?

Comment: I don't even have an apt-show command on my current install. Must be an extra/optional package that provides that?

Comment: @TravisGriggs The command is `apt-show-versions`, from the package of the same name.

Comment: `what you are looking for?`  He explicitly asked for `apt-get`, but one can infer that he was just evading `apt`'s inconsistent output by any other solution